# When is a cone a vector bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, schemes

Is there a ''nice'' criterion for when a cone, i.e. a scheme of the form $\operatorname{Spec}_X S^{\bullet}$, where $S^{\bullet}$ is a graded algebra and $X$ is a scheme, is a vector bundle?

Comment: what do you mean by $S$? some graded algebra?

Comment: I guess you could say something like, $S_0 \cong \mathcal{O_X}$ and the natural map $\mathrm{Sym}(S_1) \to S$ is an isomorphism.